# SetInterval for different messages with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
var i = 0;
var sampleMessages = ["First message", "Second message", "Third"];

heartbeatInterval = setInterval(function() {
  while (i <= sampleMessages.length) {
    alert(sampleMessages);
    window.eval(eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat", data));
  }
}, 5000)
```

I am trying to build a application and I am facing a problem using `setInterval`.
I am using `setInterval` where I can send a message for a particular time interval. But I want to send different messages.

For example if my time interval is 5000, the first message must be *message1* and after five seconds the second message must be *message2* and so on. I want the code purely in JavaScript not in jQuery or others.

Comment: Go ahead, try something, if it fails, come back, **show your attempt** and we'll help to fix it.

Comment: it is working for same message but i want help in sending different messages

Comment: Then you are going to have to post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post your code so we can help you figure figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
    alert("Hello!");
}
See here the alert box will produce message hello for every 3 seconds. Now i want to post different messages like hi,bye, see you soon. I mean can i give this messages in an array and call that array

Comment: So have a queue of messages and pick them off one by one.

Comment: @johnmathew Look, I understand you frustration because from your end you are thinking 'I asked my question why can't i get a straight answer' but you have to see it from our side. What does your existing code look like? and how is the new feature of different messages based on time going to fit in? and all the other questions that are answered with a simple snippet of your code. We want to help but we need the full picture, if you don't want to expect answers like "keep a counter and send the next message based on that".

Comment: i mean i am thinking to place messages in an array and then call that array but i dont know how it works

Comment: @johnmathew `let myMessages = ["message 1", "message 2"]; ... alert(myMessages.pop);`

Comment: @AdamH sorry i am new to this stackoverflow so i didnt know how to ask the question sorry if my comments are rude will try to comment with more polite from this time

Comment: @johnmathew no worries man, we all start somewhere. Just take a couple minutes and put a snippet of your code in the original question (edit, don't post as a comment) and I'm sure someone will help you out.

Comment: `window.eval(eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat", data));` you don't need the `window.eval` part, just call the function directly `eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat", data);`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a loop in the function, as that will process the entire array each time the function runs. Instead, the index should be declared outside the interval function, you should just increment the index once, and display that message.

Also, you should use `<` when comparing the index with the array length.

```js
var messageIndex = 0;
heartbeatInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if (messageIndex < sampleMessages.length) {
    alert(sampleMessages[messageIndex]);
    window.eval(eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat", data));
    messageIndex++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(heartbeatInterval);
  }
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be showing the messages in a specific order over a specific interval you can use something like this. I changed it to use `console.log` instead of `alert` due to alert potentially blocking the next notification.

```js
var i = 0;
var sampleMessages = ["First message", "Second message", "Third"];

var heartbeatInterval = setInterval(function() {
  // if we still have messages to show
  if (sampleMessages.length > 0) {
    // display the next message from the array
    console.log(sampleMessages.shift());
  } else {
    // clear the interval, we don't have any messages left to display
    clearInterval(heartbeatInterval);
  }
}, 5000)
```

A key to this is the [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) method which removes the first element in the array and returns it. Another important aspect of this is the call to [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) which stops your interval when you don't have any messages left to display. so setInterval returns an ID of the interval and you pass that to clearInterval to stop the timer.

**EDIT:** 
If you just need to send "heartbeat" + an incremented count then you can just do something simple like this:

```js
var heartBeatCount = 1;

setInterval(function() {
  // this assumes the data property you passing here needs to be the count
  // if thats not the case the use this instead
  // eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat" + (heartBeatCount++), data)
  eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat", heartBeatCount++)
}, 5000)
```

Comment: what if instead of hi bye i want hearbeat 1, heart beat 2, heartbeat 3......heartbeat n. i dont know how many heartbeats i want as long as my application runs i want setinterval to run

Comment: That changes things. Is the heartbeat going to do anything aside from show a message box? like do an ajax post or something to keep a session alive?

Comment: If you don't actually need to show anything and just call your heartbeat function just remove all the stuff in the interval and just add a call to `eoWebBrowser.extInvoke("applicationHeartbeat", data)`

Comment: @AdamH I would argue against using `shift` just because... (why?). It mutates the original array which is usually a bad thing, it is far slower than simple iteration and it doesn't really simplify the code that much to be worth the trouble.

Comment: @MatusDubrava good point, iunno why I went with it, I just threw something together because I was fairly certain the actual requirements were different from just showing the messages in the array. You're correct though, for efficiency just use store the last index that was displayed.

Comment: The reason for heartbeat is to make sure the session is alive and make sure that the connections are still intact. So, as long as the connection are intact it means that the application is running. so,  i need to send the messages to make sure that hey i am receiving hearbeat message1 and then heartbeat message 2 and so on. I dont know how long the application will run thats the reason i proposed that from heartbeat message 1 to n.

Comment: @johnmathew I updated my answer with another solution to just run the heartbeat.